# return longest word and its length in the same function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Hello i am trying to return the longest word and his lenght in the same function but so far what ever tried i wasnt succeful , i was able to return the world and the lenght in a diffrent function but what i want is to return both of them in the same function

```
function longestWord(string) {
    var str = string.split(" ");
    var longest = 0;
    var word = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length 1; i++) {
        if (longest < str[i].length) {
            longest = str[i].length;
            word = str[i];
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```

Comment: can't you just get the length of the word with `word.length` afterwards ?

Comment: You have to return json data with "word" and "length".

Comment: @DragonRock you are right

Comment: As @DragonRock said, it's much better way. But if you are adamant about returning both, do it using an object. `return { word : word, length : word.length }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) to convert your string into an array of object. Every object will have the word and its length. Then use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) to get the object with the highest length.

```js
const data = 'Some random data';

const result = data
  .split(' ')
  .map(word => ({ word, len: word.length }))
  .reduce((carry, el) => carry.len > el.len ? carry : el);
  
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is a clean solution. Neat.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are doing some particularly weird things, you shouldn't need to send both the word and its length. Since the word is a string, you can get its length later on like so

```
 word.length
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest and shortest way to do. Use `reduce`, `length` and `match`:

```js
function longestWordOf(str) {
  return str.match(/\w+/g).reduce((p, c) => p.length > c.length ? p : c);
}

var str = 'Hello stackOverlfow users, how are you all doing?';
var longestString = longestWordOf(str);
console.log('Longest word is \'' + longestString + '\' with length ' + longestString.length);
```